# Loops in SAS macro

Tags: loops, macros, sas

I try to calculate an additional w column to my table but my macro does not work appropriately.

**I got an errors**

> 1. The condition in the %DO %WHILE loop, t1.r(&i) EQ t1.r(&i+1), yielded an invalid or missing value, .

If anyone helps me I would really appreciate.

```
%macro abc();
    proc sql;
        CREATE TABLE work.temp AS SELECT
            %let i=1;
            %do %while (t1.r(&i) EQ t1.r(&i+1));
                %if t1.td(&i) EQ t1.rd(&i) 
                    %then t1.c(&i)*t1.r(&i)-*t1.t(&i) as w;
                    %else t1.c(&i)*t1.r(&i)-0.11314*t1.t(&i) as w;
                %let i =  %eval(&i + 1);
            %end;
        FROM WORK.table t1
    quit;
%mend abc;
%abc();
```

table:

```
    m  rd     r      c       tem    td    t
  1002  t   28,393  50%     Tem-01  t   6,000
  1002  t   28,393  50%     Tem-02  e   4,000
  1002  t   28,393  50%     Tem-03  u   8,000
  1002  t   28,393  50%     Tem-04  t   6,000
  1002  t   28,393  50%     Tem-05  e   15,000
  1002  t   28,393  50%     Tem-06  u   52,000
  1002  u   14,746  100%    Tem-01  t   6,000
  1002  u   14,746  100%    Tem-02  e   4,000
  1002  u   14,746  100%    Tem-03  u   8,000
  1002  u   14,746  100%    Tem-04  t   6,000
  1002  u   14,746  100%    Tem-05  e   15,000
  1002  u   14,746  100%    Tem-06  u   52,000
  1002  u   21,847  50%     Tem-01  t   6,000
  1002  u   21,847  50%     Tem-02  e   4,000
  1002  u   21,847  50%     Tem-03  u   8,000
  1002  u   21,847  50%     Tem-04  t   6,000
  1002  u   21,847  50%     Tem-05  e   15,000
  1002  u   21,847  50%     Tem-06  u   52,000
  1003  u   10,000  50%     Tem-01  u   8,000
  1004  t   10,000  20%     Tem-02  u   5,000
  1005  t   10,000  20%     Tem-03  t   8,000
  1006  u   1,000   50%     Tem-04  t   5,000
```

Comment: Please describe in words what your new column should be. Alternatively, give us the table you expect as a result.

Comment: please check if you did not forget a factor in the `%then` statement

Comment: Your WHILE() condition will always be false.  Macro logic cannot see the values of variables in datasets.  So you are just comparing two strings that are always different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you not just using a CASE statement to decide which calculation to perform for each observation?  Here is your sample data:

```
data have;
  input m rd $ r c tem $ td $ t ;
  informat r t comma7. c percent. ;
cards;
  1002  t   28,393  50%     Tem-01  t   6,000
  1002  t   28,393  50%     Tem-02  e   4,000
  1002  t   28,393  50%     Tem-03  u   8,000
  1002  t   28,393  50%     Tem-04  t   6,000
  1002  t   28,393  50%     Tem-05  e   15,000
  1002  t   28,393  50%     Tem-06  u   52,000
  1002  u   14,746  100%    Tem-01  t   6,000
  1002  u   14,746  100%    Tem-02  e   4,000
  1002  u   14,746  100%    Tem-03  u   8,000
  1002  u   14,746  100%    Tem-04  t   6,000
  1002  u   14,746  100%    Tem-05  e   15,000
  1002  u   14,746  100%    Tem-06  u   52,000
  1002  u   21,847  50%     Tem-01  t   6,000
  1002  u   21,847  50%     Tem-02  e   4,000
  1002  u   21,847  50%     Tem-03  u   8,000
  1002  u   21,847  50%     Tem-04  t   6,000
  1002  u   21,847  50%     Tem-05  e   15,000
  1002  u   21,847  50%     Tem-06  u   52,000
  1003  u   10,000  50%     Tem-01  u   8,000
  1004  t   10,000  20%     Tem-02  u   5,000
  1005  t   10,000  20%     Tem-03  t   8,000
  1006  u   1,000   50%     Tem-04  t   5,000
;;;;
```

Here is code to calculate W.

```
proc sql noprint ;
 create table want as
   select *
        , case when td=rd then c*r-t
               else c*r-0.11314*t
          end as w
   from have
 ;
quit;
```